# Error in setting job.setInputFormatClass in Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a MapReduce program. I need to give input text file in the format of KEYVALUE pair. so that If I write

```
job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
```

The eclipse compiler is showing error that I cant use InputFormat.
anyhow I need to set the Input's format as KeyValueTextInputFormat 
 How do I do this ?? Any IDea ?????

My Code is

`

```
package com.iot.dictionary;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;


import com.iot.dictionary.Dictionary.AllTranslationsReducer;
import com.iot.dictionary.Dictionary.WordMapper;
public class Driver2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
          System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
          System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job = new Job(conf, "dictionary");
        System.out.println("Job-> "+job.toString());
        job.setJarByClass(Dictionary.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(AllTranslationsReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using new Hadoop API (Hadoop 0.20.2 and above), you have to import the KeyValueTextInputFormat.class class from package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat and if you are using the old Hadoop API, you have to import it from org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat

You see that line in your code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
```

Change it to

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: thanks even if i import I do get the same compiler error! how can I set the KeyValueInputFormat to the job??

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the basic code you have been using along with the imported packages.

Comment: As I guessed, package import problem. I have edited my answer, have a look. Thanks.